# Consuming a DataPower service which is not WCF and involving X509 cert in a Console Application

Tags: httpwebrequest, x509certificate, ibm-datapower

I have a service which is not built in .Net and requires a X509 certificate authentication. The services requires a soap string to be sent. I have built the soap manually and added the X509 cert to the httpwebrequest but when i read the response i get the "Service Not Authenticated" response.

However when i use the same soap string from SoapUI Client, right click and add the ougoing wss->" Apply Cert name" , it adds the wsse:Security elements dynamically and then when i run the request it gives me the response

So, the question i have is how do i add the wsse:Security elements using the X509 cert dynamically  in the headers

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Err, to what "headers" do you want to add it? What tool do you use when you get the Not-Authenticated response? With curl you can use the -E option.

Comment: Hi Stefan, i want to add the <wsse:security> element to the Soap header.This contains the digital signature in it but i wonder how do i add that digital signature using the certificate to the soap header

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, no idea what the best way for that would be